# how to set up assembla svn repository on mac

Tags: macos, svn, repository, assembla

How to export local repository maintained on mac platform to assembla SVN

I tried exporting my repository then zip it and it import it into assemble, I get the following error each time.

> ERROR - There is no breakout.ini in SVN
>   /mnt/atl-fs8-data1/svn/myproject we trying to backup

I also tried checking out a working copy to the url I am given

https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/mysecretproject/

that did not work either.

It is probably easy on windows platform but all my code is on mac. I am stuck with it for 2 days now.

Answer (score 1):

Have you asked on their support sites? If not, you can

- [Ask user community](http://forum.assembla.com)
- [File a new support ticket](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/AssemblaSupport/support/tickets)

Answer (score 0):

How did you export your repository?

My advice is to follow the instructions in SVN Tool:

1. Dump the repo with "svnadmin dump"
2. Import the dump by uploading it
   (if smaller than 200 MB) or providing url for assembla to download
   it

If this does not work, you can open up a support ticket and attach the repo dump you are trying to import

Comment: I used Export menu in Cornerstone. Did not use shell command. This did not come to mind, it could be a bug coz it is such a basic feature. Will ask on their forum.